# django-haystack and solr setup issue (undefined field text error)

Tags: solr, django-haystack

I am new to Solr. I have been following the documentation provided in the http://haystacksearch.org/ site.
My project is on django 1.4.

The steps I followed:

1.Added haystack to installed apps.

2.Modified settings.py with

```
HAYSTACK_SITECONF = 'directory.search_sites'
HAYSTACK_SEARCH_ENGINE = 'solr'
HAYSTACK_SOLR_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr'
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr'
        # ...or for multicore...
        # 'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/mysite',
        },
}
```

3.My search_indexes.py file

```
from haystack import indexes
from app.models import SellerItem


class SellerItemIndex(indexes.SearchIndex):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    sub_title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='sub_title')
    description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='description')

    def get_model(self):
        return SellerItem

    def index_queryset(self):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(pk__gt=0)
```

4.Added search_sites.py

```
import haystack
haystack.autodiscover()
```

5.added templates/search/indexes/selleritem.txt

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.sub_title }}
{{ object.description }}
```

6.Added this to urls.py:

```
(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
```

7.Created search template

8.Replaced schema.xml in apache-solr-3.6.0/example/solr/conf with the generated xml by using the command:

```
python manage.py build_solr_schema
```

I am getting an error like this when I start the solr server:

```
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field text
at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1330)
at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$SolrQueryAnalyzer.getAnalyzer(IndexSchema.java:408)
at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$SolrIndexAnalyzer.reusableTokenStream(IndexSchema.java:383)
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.getFieldQuery(QueryParser.java:574)
at org.apache.solr.search.SolrQueryParser.getFieldQuery(SolrQueryParser.java:206)
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:1429)
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:1317)
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:1245)
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:1234)
at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:206)
at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParserPlugin.java:79)
at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:143)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:105)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:165)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
at org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener.newSearcher(QuerySenderListener.java:59)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore$3.call(SolrCore.java:1182)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Still the server will be starting
When I do ./manage.py rebuild_index and do a search I get an error log

```
Problem accessing /solr/select/. Reason:undefined field text
```

What did I miss? Did anyone had the same issue before?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue stems from the incorrectly named template. You use `search/indexes/selleritem.txt`, but it should be `search/indexes/app/selleritem_text.txt`.

As a side note, I see that you’re mixing Haystack 1.X and 2.X settings and methods. By the lack of the `indexes.Indexable` mixin in your `SellerItemIndex` search index class, it appears that you must actually be using 1.X. Your life will be simpler if you stick with the docs for the version you are using.

- [1.2.7 docs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.7/)
- [2.0.0-beta docs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Hope that helps,

Ben

Comment: Thanks a bunch @benspaulding!!!!. I didn't realize I was looking at the wrong docs all this time